# Can multiple laravel applications use the same composer folder provider?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, shared-hosting

I have the following situation:

I use shared hosting with a limit of 400,000 inodes.

I have at least 20 laravel projects, which are already bursting this limit. I would like to know if there is a possibility for all projects to use the same vendor folder (for composer files), so it would drastically reduce the amount of files and solve my problem.

Comment: Why should that be possible? Why not split your projects up unto multiple servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's the bad idea to use as multiple projects surely have different packages installed and it makes no sense to do so...